# Is it possible to profile only a plugin shared library without impacting main program?

Tags: shared-libraries, profiling

Is it possible to profile only a shared library without looking the main program ?
For example, I developed a plugin and I would like to profile but with no need to profile the whole application. I just want to see the bottleneck of my plugin. (Of course, I would like to profile it while the main application is running and has loaded my plugin...)

I'm working on linux and I'm used to callgrind, but for the curiosity, I'm also interested by the possibilities on all systems, so I let the question general.

I'm interested in this because the main program is quite slow, and don't want to add the overhead of profiling on since I'm not interested by the main program performance here...

Answer (score 1):

In Linux [`perf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perf_(Linux)) [statistical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)#Statistical_profilers) profiling tool has very low overhead (1-2%), so you can profile entire application with [`perf record ./your_application`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-record.1.html) and then analyze generated profile `perf.data` with [`perf report` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-report.1.html). You may filter perf report output to some shared libraries or search function names of your plugin. Read more at http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html

Callgrind is not just a profiler, it is binary recompiler used to implement exact [profiler with instrumentation approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)#Instrumentation) and it has 10-20 times overhead for any code, even when profiling tool is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin only runs during certain times, right? Like when the user requests certain activities? People use [*this method*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) with any IDE, manually pausing during that time. The pause will land in the plugin according to how much time it uses. Before you pause there is no performance impact because the app runs full speed, while in the pause, it is stopped, which you don't care because you're diagnosing your plugin.